# Enumerating CertificateAuthority.EncodeCRLDistInfo using Powershell

Tags: powershell, com, x509, pki

I'm attempting to extract X509 certificate extensions information from a Microsoft CA using Powershell.  This is a proof-of-concept more than anything.

I've used the `CertificateAuthority.View` COM Object to access the CA database then enumerate each row in the extensions table with `EnumCertViewExtension(0)` in order to access the columns.  I'm extracting the column values with `GetValue(PROTOTYPE_BINARY,CV_OUT_BASE)` which returns the value of the extension as a Base64 encoded string.

The above works as I can decode this Base64 data using `System.Security.Cryptography.AsnEncodedData` as shown in the first part of the example below.  The downside to this method is that it only returns the values as a single string per distribution point (in a similar format to the `certutil.exe` utility) therefore extracting the URL would involve further parsing of this string with a regex or similar.

My alternative thought is to try to decode the data with `CertificateAuthority.EncodeCRLDistInfo` as I've had success with other extensions and COM Objects in converting the values to XML and/or JSON which are easier to manipulate later.

However, this particular option gives strange results.  It seems to fully decode the first Base64 string in the array, but fails to do so for the other three strings.

The following MCV example shows this.

```ps
# These are the raw Base64 encoded values for the CRL Distribution Point extension as extracted
# from the CA's Db by enumerating CertificateAuthority.View.1
$cdpArr = @(
    "MD4wPKA6oDiGNmh0dHA6Ly9wa2kud2luZG93cy50ZXN0L2NkcC9XaW5UZXN0LUlzc3VpbmctQ0EyKDEpLmNybA==",
    "MDswOaA3oDWGM2h0dHA6Ly9wa2kud2luZG93cy50ZXN0L2NkcC9XaW5UZXN0LUlzc3VpbmctQ0EyLmNybA==",
    "MDswOaA3oDWGM2h0dHA6Ly9wa2kud2luZG93cy50ZXN0L2NkcC9XaW5kb3dzVGVzdC1Sb290LUNBLmNybA==",
    "MDkwN6A1oDOGMWh0dHA6Ly9wa2kud2luZG93cy50ZXN0L2NkcC9XaW5UZXN0LVBvbGljeS1DQS5jcmw="
)

# The next three lines display all four CRL Distribution Points, so the input data must be good.
Foreach ($cdp in $cdpArr) {
    $cdpASN = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.AsnEncodedData("2.5.29.31",[convert]::FromBase64String($cdp))
    $cdpASN.format($true)       
}

# The following only displays one CRL Distribution Point URL
Foreach ($cdp in $cdpArr) {
    $cdpObj = new-object -ComObject CertificateAuthority.EncodeCRLDistInfo
    $cdpASN = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.AsnEncodedData("2.5.29.31",[convert]::FromBase64String($cdp))
    $bString = ([system.text.encoding]::Unicode).GetString($cdpASN.RawData)
    $cdpObj.Decode($bString)
    For ($i=0; $i -lt $cdpObj.GetDistPointCount(); $i++){
        For ($j=0; $j -lt $cdpObj.GetNameCount($i); $j++) {
            "CDP {0}, Name {1}, Choice {2}, URL {3}" -f $i, $j, $cdpObj.GetNameChoice($i,$j), $cdpObj.GetName($i,$j)
        }
    }
    Remove-Variable cdpASN, cdpObj # just in-case something lingers
}
```

The first part returns the following, which shows all four distribution points being decoded successfully, but as four strings unfortunately:

```
[1]CRL Distribution Point
     Distribution Point Name:
          Full Name:
               URL=http://pki.windows.test/cdp/WinTest-Issuing-CA2(1).crl

[1]CRL Distribution Point
     Distribution Point Name:
          Full Name:
               URL=http://pki.windows.test/cdp/WinTest-Issuing-CA2.crl

[1]CRL Distribution Point
     Distribution Point Name:
          Full Name:
               URL=http://pki.windows.test/cdp/WindowsTest-Root-CA.crl

[1]CRL Distribution Point
     Distribution Point Name:
          Full Name:
               URL=http://pki.windows.test/cdp/WinTest-Policy-CA.crl
```

The second part returns the following, showing the first distribution point URL but none of the subsequent ones.

```
CDP 0, Name 0, Choice 7, URL http://pki.windows.test/cdp/WinTest-Issuing-CA2(1).crl
CDP 0, Name 0, Choice 7, URL 
CDP 0, Name 0, Choice 7, URL 
CDP 0, Name 0, Choice 7, URL
```

If I rearrange the order in the array, the fully successful decode moves accordingly - that is, the first string in the array as shown above always fully decodes regardless of its position, while the other three fail to display the URL.

Initial thoughts suggest a problem with the Base64 strings - but they all fully decode with the first method, ruling that out.

Next on the hit list would be the string conversion around `[system.text.encoding]::Unicode`, but in all cases, the ASN.1 must successfully decode as the `GetNameChoice()` method always returns a 7, effectively ruling that out too (maybe!).

Is this a bug or have I missed something?